# Yii2 notification system implementation

Tags: email, yii2, chat, message, vote

I am trying to implement simple notification system in Yii2. 
I have a list of Records populated in ListView. 
I would like to allow users to vote for this records. Only once per Record.
Also the Author of each record must be notified (smth like new incoming emails) about who voted for his Record.
What is the easiest way to implement this in Yii2?
Thanks for an advice!

Comment: The easiest way is to use events. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html

Comment: Thanks for a link. As I understood, with events I can get and process the data from user (this I can also do with controller/action), but how to notify a user that he got new message (new record in DB)? Is there an event which can trigger server push? Or where I can find simple explanation or example about how it works?

Comment: Do you know how to use JS events, like onclick, etc? This is the same. You register event, register event handler, trigger that event and process your own logic in handler. It may be like sending email, updating db, anything what you want.

Comment: Editing..)Pressed enter

Comment: Imagine following case. 'User A' clicked a button and 'User B' obtain a message 'clicked'. So, the logic should be like following: 
- Trigger an event after click on button by 'User A'. Event handler will insert one row to DB. (This is clear)
- Generate an event to notify 'User B'. (This I can not understand still. How to send data to 'User B' without any action from his side. Or 'User B' should also check DB periodically with Pjax as esample?)
P.S. What is the difference beetwen an event attached for example to button and controller/action for this button?

Comment: Try https://github.com/webzop/yii2-notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With php only you can't do that, you need to have js at some point.

Solution One could be, from user B side you keep asking the server after certain time (using ajax), if anything(event) happened. If it does return the result with that ajax and update the page.
But then again this is not a very good practice.

If you really want a **Real Time** update, you might want to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/). Then again using php socket is a bad idea.

So here comes the Solution Two: `yii2 + redis + nodejs + socket`

**redis** will do the communication between yii2 and nodejs. The idea is, if anything (event or update) happens yii2 will **publish** a `event` with associate `data` to redis `channel` and nodejs which is listening to that channel will catch that event and send the data (or update) to client using socket.

[Here is a real time chat application tutorial using yii2+redis+nodejs+socket.](https://www.my-yii.com/learn/view-episode/yii-2-real-time-chat-app-with-nodejs-socketio-and-redisio)

Comment: Thank you for a link. It is very useful. But which way can I get an ID of a new connected client? What is the best practice to filter messages (as example if I need to send a message to one specific user)? Should I create a new channel for it? Or should I create filter inside socket (notification.js according mentioned example)? I can PUBLISH to a channel the IDs of sender and target user but how to get user ($thismodel->ID) inside socket js code in order to check if current user is real target?

Comment: you can get socket ID inside this `io.on('connection', function (socket) {` **`socket.id`** will give you the ID you should store it somehow then when send message to user instead of `socket.emit` use **`io.sockets.to(socketId).emit`** where **socketId** is specific user's socket id